# How do I login to aws cognito only with username, without password

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

The requirement is that an admin should be able to login as any user anytime with just username. So I need a way to authenticate a user with just a username and no password. Is there a way for that in aws cognito? Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you've got [this](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js/) and [this](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/advanced/q/platform/js/) so you can not sign in as a different user using just the username.